# UI tests NoMatchingViewException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I try to create a tests, but get NoMatchingViewException.

I have First and Camera Fragments. First fragment tests are ok, but Camera are not.

I tried using ViewMatchers.withText and downgrading Espresso to espresso-core:3.3.0.

I try onView(withId(R.id.myTestId)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed()))) also.

What else can I do? Please help me

Code:

```
@get:Rule
    var activityRule: ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity> =
        ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

@Test
    fun chekSwitchBtnVisibility() {
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.fabSwitch))
            .check(matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))
    }
```

MainActivity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_mainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graf" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Camera Fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_cameraFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/previewView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_switch"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabAddPhoto"
        android:title="@string/cameraBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ibGallery"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/fabSwitch" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibGallery"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_outer_circle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/gallery_button_alt"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_photo" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: ca u post ur activity layout xml code?

Comment: done, added at post

Comment: Have you disabled the animation?

Comment: @iamanbansal No, what animation?

Comment: you have to disable the system animation for UI test, so the action and view can sync up

Comment: @iamanbansa I just did it, but the result is the same(((

Comment: Is `FAB` is visible to you during test execution?

Comment: @iamanbansa No, I get NoMatchingViewException again(((

Comment: Maybe the fragment isn't being added to the container. Check by running the app

Comment: @iamanbansa I think you're right, thank you!